# Integral over sphere $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}e^{-\Vert x-\varphi \Vert^2} x \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I am looking for a way to evaluate the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}e^{-\Vert x-y \Vert^2} x \ dS(x)  \text{ for a fixed vector }y \in \mathbb R^n.$$

Here $dS$ is the surface measure.
I am sorry that I have no ideas about the way to approach this.

Comment: Where did you find this question from? You might get some idea from the source

Comment: The $dx$ confuses me. Did you mean to have that be the surface measure and we are integrating only $S^{n-1}$, or did you mean for that to be the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and we are integrating on the unit ball?

Comment: Writing $ f(y) = \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} e^{-\|x-y\|^2} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}x) $, where $\sigma$ is the surface measure on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, we have $$f(y) = \frac{2\pi^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})}e^{-(1+\|y\|^2)}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\|y\|\cos\varphi}\sin^{n-2}\varphi\,\mathrm{d}\varphi.$$ Then using $$\nabla f(y)= \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} 2(x-y) e^{-\|x-y\|^2} \, \sigma(\mathrm{d}x),$$ your integral can be written as $$\frac{\nabla f(y)}{2}+yf(y).$$

Comment: You might take a look again [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for how to write a good question, with an emphasis on [avoiding "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).